# mks to srt conversion

Tags: subtitle

It's easy to extract subtitles from mkv (Matroska) videos but if extracted subtitles are not in text format, they need to be converted using OCR software. Is there any program in Ubuntu available to convert mks or pgs subtitles to srt?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Subtitle Edit**, it works on Ubuntu. To install it run

```
sudo apt install mono-complete libhunspell-dev libmpv-dev tesseract-ocr
```

You may also need to install some *tesseract-ocr-???* packages if you want to convert subtitles in languages other than English.

Download the portable version from [here](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases) and unzip it to wherever you want.

Now you can run the program with

```
mono /path/to/SubtitleEdit.exe
```

[This](http://hometheatersns.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-extract-pgs-subtitles-and-convert-pgs-to-srt--from-mkv.html) is how to convert PGS subtitles to SRT using Subtitle Edit.